# Advice on Glyphicon Bugs?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm fairly new to glyphicons and am trying to figure out what makes them so temperamental. I have them on several websites, and I often find that a particular glyphicon doesn't display, or sometimes no glyphicons will display on a particular website.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<li><a href="/topics/vertebrate-physiology" title="Vertebrate Physiology">5. Vertebrate Physiology <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" style="font-size: 125%; color: #fff;"></span></li>
```

The weird thing is everything works fine when I link to the online style sheet @ https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css

But if I copy the styles from that into a file of the same name on my computer and link it, it doesn't work. I confirmed that I'm correctly linked to it.

So it looks like I can only use glyphicons on one of my local websites if I'm linked to an online style sheet. Why can't I use a local style sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to the relative paths to the fonts. Looking at https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css, you could see something like:

```
url(../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf)
```

The fonts folder is relative to the css file which is `https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css` so that it's downloaded correctly.

It does not work on your local because the fonts folder is missing on your local web server. If you want it to work on your local, you also have to download the fonts folder and put it in the correct folder relative to your `bootstrap.css`

Comment: Actually, I do have a fonts folder, but it must be in the wrong location. I'll move it around, or change the path in the style sheet. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you didn't have fonts folder in expected place .. search in your downloaded CSS file for **../fonts/** and you will get the idea.

> the best way to download bootstrap from [here](http://getbootstrap.com)