# Bootstrap Glyphicons working locally, but not on host

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I am having trouble with the Bootstrap Glyphicons not showing as soon as put on my host. I have no clue what would cause this, as it works perfectly fine locally on my PC - the host is an exact copy of my local folder, but still it just doesn't really seem to work.

**This is what it looks like locally;**

[image]

as it should

**How it looks on the host;**

[image]

As said, I have no idea what would cause this at all. Help much appriciated ^_^

Comment: try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32021214/advice-on-glyphicon-bugs/32021621#32021621

Comment: can you check the network and see if there is any 404?

Comment: looks like you have encoding problems on your host. Make sure that your files are saved in utf-8 encode.